# Predefined Neural Networks instead of fine tuning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I usually try to form my ANNs with classic fine-tuning approach but I recently learned that there are different "predefined" networks specially for certain tasks. Is there a good summary about these? Are they really perform better than home-made ones?

Comment: "predefined networks" --> what is predefined? the weights? the architecture?

Comment: Predefined = pre trained with both architecture and weights. For instance, Xception, VGG16, VGG19, ResNet50, InceptionV3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you are doing a task for which the weights of a very large network, trained on the same type of problem, are present, then it's better to use the weights of that pre-trained network. You can also fine tune the layers later on. One such example is the VGG16 Net. This NN was used in the ImageNet challenge in 2014, hence if you are trying to do image classification tasks where your images are the subset of ImageNet, then you should use the pre-trained VGG16 weights. [This](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) is a great tutorial if you want to go in details.

But the above situation might not be true in every case. For example, the above case is not true if you reverse the situation.

Comment: I think that it is quite unprobable that one has to deal with an ImageNet subset in real projects so if this particular pre-trained network is only good for this case, then this is not especially helpful. The question is iwhether VGG16 is also good for similar task with different images or not.

Comment: As per my knowledge, if a NN has not learned the features of something because it has never seen such a thing, then it will be of no use to apply that network for such kind of problem